# Rails eager load with has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got two models, `Post` and `Tag`, that are associated using `has_and_belongs_to_many`. I have an action to loads the posts for a specific tag, and I would like to eagerly load each post's other tags.

I tried using

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :posts, -> { includes :tags }
```

on the `Tag` model, and tried using

```
@posts = @tag.posts.where(approved: true).includes(:tags)
```

in the controller action, but in both cases, N+1 queries were run when rendering

```
post.tags.pluck(:name).join(', ')
```

in the view.

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or am I not able to use eager loading when referring to the same table?

Comment: shouldn't it be .includes(:tags), with a plural includeS?

Comment: My bad, it is actually that in my code. I'll edit the post now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick play in the console, it seems like `pluck` does it's own database call. You should instead get the names from the eager-loaded tags some other way, for example using `map`:

```
post.tags.map{ |tag| tag.name }.join(', ')
```

Comment: While it doesn't seem ideal, this does work. Thankfully ruby has the shorthand notation with map: `post.tags.map(&:name).join(',')`

Comment: Cool, I actually didn't know that one :)